# unity3d TCP client check every second or every frame

Tags: unity-game-engine, tcpclient

What is better or what is commonly used in all games i mean check streamReader each frame if data available or every second or more for games like FPS?

like this or no?

```
void Update() {
if(connected) {
try {
    if(theStream.DataAvailable) {
   String data = sr.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Real-world applications that handle network connections generally check them continuously. They either do this by blocking a thread on the connection or by blocking on both the connection and a timer when they have no work to do.

Comment: Can you open a little more about this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should better make sure not depending on the frame, but make updates based on the calculated ping

Comment: Hmm, you can use system ping (crazy), or.. calculate time bettwen (start your request) and get server responde

Comment: but with the TCP client when i write something to server i dont wait response for that because there is no callback like http requests.

Comment: client send his action, and get updated data (about enviroment) from server (good?)

Comment: what did you mean with "depending on a frame"?

Comment: Depend on clients action :)

Server accept/reject clients Action, and (After recive result (client got updated frame))



Hmm, natural way is (Frame result (what see you or other clients)) is depend on the result from serwer.